# How to use async/await in scenario with multiple tasks with each task requiring a new async/await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have the following scenario:

Customer has a number of accounts, each of them has a number of cards attached.

Now I have a request where I need to query accounts with cards on multiple customers. I have async methods to query accounts and cards separately, i.e. `FindAccounts(string customer)`, `FindCards(string[] accounts)`.

So I have this method:

```
public async Task<Data> FindCustomersWithCards(string[] customers)
{
     var accountsTasks = customers.Select(_service.FindAccounts);
     var accounts = await Task.WhenAll(accountsTasks);

     var cardsTasks = accounts.Select(_service.FindCards);
     var cards = await Tasks.WhenAll(cardsTasks)        
     ...
}
```

While this will work it has a problem that you have to wait for accounts of all customers to be finished before cards can be queried. A more efficient implementation would go on and query cards for customer accounts as soon as accounts querying for a particular customer is finished (without waiting for other customers).

My question is if it is possible to do this with `async/await`. I think I can manage with `ContinueWith`, but I am not 100% sure it is OK to mix `async/await` with `ContinueWith` approach.

Comment: You are right, ContinueWith sounds like what you want. You will build up a bigger task "Get account and then get cards" for each account

Comment: What about mixing two approaches? Do you know of any drawbacks of that?

Comment: Yeah I meant mixing it, you can await on a ContinueWith, basically you can await in anything that return a Task and ContinueWith does. If you show your method signatures I can provide oyu an example code

Comment: Obviously what you've shown isn't the real code (since it doesn't return anything). Do you, in your final form, only require the cards? You're only obtaining the accounts as an intermediate step and don't need them for anything else?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This was pseudo code just to show the most important part. I do need all the data for all the calls in the result, i.e. Customers with Accounts with Cards. I have edited the question a bit.

Comment: @Juan Thanks for help, I can manage mixing them. I am only afraid of some side affects that might be a result of this mixing, because TPL is quite a complex topic and I am sure I don't know all of the details :)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Instead of writing complicated code, just create an asynchronous *function* that does what you want for a single customer and call it once for each customer. TPL with `async/await` is *no* more complex that writing the equivalent synchronous code

Comment: BTW, what does the service call? If it calls the database, you'll get orders of magnitude better performance *and* cleaner code by executing a *single* query that returns all accounts and cards whose customers are in a specific list.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know, but I did not design the data store and have no control over it, just these 2 calls. I think I got what you mean, thank you. I'll try to do this (hope I understood you correctly): just add the `async FindAccountsWithCards(string customer)` that will do await on `FindAccounts` and then will await  on `FindCards`. And if I now create an array of these tasks and do WhenAll on them it will achieve what I want. Strange I did not think of this solution.

Comment: For future reference, do *not* use `ContinueWith`. It is a low-level, dangerous API. You should always use `await` instead of `ContinueWith` for asynchronous code. For 99% of the "process tasks as they complete" questions, the better answer is "introduce another `async` method".

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes, thank you. I have read other answers by you and that's why I tried to avoid it, but did not figure out how. Though I don't really know why they are "dangerous", I suppose it takes a lot of knowledge of the framework to answer that one :)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik: [`ContinueWith` has the same problems as `StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be more sensible to split it by customer and async within that:

```
private async Task<Card> FindCardForCustomerAsync(string customer)
{
  var account = await _service.FindAccountAsync(customer);
  return await _service.FindCardAsync(account);
}

public async Task<Data> FindCustomersWithCards(string[] customers)
{
  var cardsTasks = customers.Select(FindCardForCustomerAsync);
  var cards = await Tasks.WhenAll(cardsTasks)
  …
}
```

However, it's worth considering the balance of efficiencies of how your `FindAccounts` and `FindCards` work. E.g. if they work as a single `SELECT` pushed to a database then the greater concurrency of turning it into multiple smaller bits of work may not be worth the greater amount of overhead that has. It can be the case that waiting for 20 or even 200 results is only marginally slower than waiting for 1, and then splitting into 20 requests gains very little, even before the extra connections involved are considered.

Comment: Thanks, it seems rather obvious now, but I did not think of it myself for some reason. @Panagiotis Kanavos have pointed out the same solution in comments. The reason that I don't have one SELECT is that I don't have control over the data store and allows only these fragmented queries. I would rather query them all if I had the chance :)

Comment: If your `FindAccounts` is making several calls behind the scenes then the odds are certainly better that this will improve things, or at least not make them worse.

Comment: `FindAccounts` does just one call really, but the problem was that I had to find accounts for ALL customers before I could continue with their cards :)

Comment: Oh, it doesn't relate to the strings you were passed?

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding here :) `FindAccounts` itself does one call, but I used it as a method group on multiple customers, so there will be multiple calls.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say if the `tasks per customer` approach will bring you the benefit, the best way to find it out is to make a test on your scenario. 


I made a simple (event that it may look quite messy) example how the first approach can be modified to allow execution of tasks per each customer.

You have mentioned that you can manage this, I just wanted to post it here so anyone interested in that can play with it.


I used `Task.Run(...)` to simulate async tasks.

```
public class Account
{
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}

public class Card
{
    public string CardName { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
}

public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
public List<Card> Cards { get; set; }

//OLD
public async Task<string[]> FindAccounts(string customer)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return Accounts.Where(a => a.CustomerName == customer).Select(a => a.AccountName).ToArray();
    });
}

//OLD
public async Task<string[]> FindCards(string[] accounts)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return Cards.Where(c => accounts.Contains(c.AccountName)).Select(a => a.CardName).ToArray();
    });
}

//NEW
public async Task<string[]> FindCards(Task<string[]> findAccountsTasks)
{
    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var accounts = await findAccountsTasks;
        return Cards.Where(c => accounts.Contains(c.AccountName)).Select(a => a.CardName).ToArray();
    });
}

//NEW
public async Task<string[]> FindCards(string customer)
{
    return await await FindAccounts(customer).ContinueWith(FindCards);
}

private async void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Accounts = new List<Account>
    {
        new Account {CustomerName = "Tomas", AccountName = "TomasAccount1"},
        new Account {CustomerName = "Tomas", AccountName = "TomasAccount2"},
        new Account {CustomerName = "Tomas", AccountName = "TomasAccount3"},
        new Account {CustomerName = "John", AccountName = "JohnAccount1"}
    };

    Cards = new List<Card>
    {
        new Card {AccountName = "TomasAccount1", CardName = "TomasAccount1Card1"},
        new Card {AccountName = "TomasAccount1", CardName = "TomasAccount1Card2"},
        new Card {AccountName = "TomasAccount1", CardName = "TomasAccount1Card3"},
        new Card {AccountName = "TomasAccount1", CardName = "TomasAccount2Card1"},
        new Card {AccountName = "JohnAccount1", CardName = "JohnAccount1Card1"},
        new Card {AccountName = "JohnAccount1", CardName = "JohnAccount1Card2"},
    };

    var customers = new List<string> { "Tomas", "John" }.ToArray();

    //OLD
    var accountstasks = customers.Select(FindAccounts);
    var accounts = await Task.WhenAll(accountstasks);

    var cardTasks = accounts.Select(FindCards);
    var cards = await Task.WhenAll(cardTasks);

    //NEW
    cardTasks = customers.Select(FindCards);
    cards = await Task.WhenAll(cardTasks);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, apparently there was a solution that is even easier and clearer :)